# How Do I get API Response Status Code Only with Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I need your help guys. I'm developing a front-end with Blazor which sends request to ASP.Net Core. 
I have the following code which gets an API response, in this case it returns the entire body of the response. What I'm trying to get here is the status code of the response only, example (200).

```
await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "https://da3.mock.pstmn.io/api/register", CurrentUser);

var response = await Http.GetStringAsync("/api/register");
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the other GetAsync method.

```cs
//var response = await Http.GetStringAsync("/api/register");
//Console.WriteLine(response);

var response = await Http.GetAsync("/api/register");
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);  // also see response.IsSuccessStatusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

For `POST` method you could use `SendAsync`, you need to use PMC to install `Newtonsoft.Json` package firstly:

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        Method = new HttpMethod("POST"),
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/api/default"),
        Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CurrentUser))

    };
requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(
            "application/json");


var result = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var responseStatusCode = result.StatusCode;
```

For `GET` method,what Henk Holterman has suggested (use `Http.GetAsync`) works well.

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0#httpclient-and-httprequestmessage-with-fetch-api-request-options